# .after not functioning as I would have expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am using .after to invoke a function which moves an image inside my GUI. When i run the code and call the function "myFunc" the image does move, but it happens instantaneously. It should gradually move across the screen. I am unsure as to why this is happening.

```
def movRight():
    global img
    global imgx
    canvas.move(imgx,20,0)
    return

def myFunc():
    moveController(1,20)
    return

def moveController(extruder, position):
    global e1current
    global e2current
    global e3current
    global e4current


    if extruder == 1:
            while position > e1current:
                print("moving")
                e1current+=1
                main.after(500,movRight)

            return
```

Comment: You are scheduling ALL of the instances of `movRight()` (`position - e1current` of them) at the same time; all of them happen in quick succession 500 milliseconds later.  What you need to do is call `movRight()` *once*, and have it schedule another call to itself if the final position hasn't been reached.

Answer (score 0):

.after does not block execution of the loop. It's more like it spawns a seperate thread which begins execution after 500 (in your case) milliseconds. In other words, .after **does not** block the loop for 500ms, call movRight and then continue the loop. Take a look at this example:

```
import tkinter as tk

def print_hi():
    print("hi")

root = tk.Tk()
for i in range(5):
    root.after(1000, print_hi)
print("loop done")
root.mainloop()
```

This outputs "loop done", and then, approximately one second later, it prints "hi" five times.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this code:

```
while position > e1current:
    main.after(500,movRight)
```

It is the same as if you had written it this way:

```
main.after(500,movRight)
main.after(500,movRight)
main.after(500,movRight)
...
```

Since calling `main.after(500,movRight)` probably executes in a millisecond or so, you are queueing up hundreds or thousands of calls that will all execute 500ms in the future.

In other words, it's no differen than if you had done this:

```
def something():
    movRight()
    movRight()
    movRight()
    ...
main.after(500,something)
```

The proper way to do an animation is to create a function that does one frame of animation, and then reschedules itself.

For example:

```
def moveController():
    movRight()
    e1current+=1
    if position > e1current:
        main.after(500, moveController)
```